# Executing an SQL query over a pandas dataset

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have a pandas data set, called 'df'.

How can I do something like below;

```
df.query("select * from df")
```

Thank you.

For those who know R, there is a library called sqldf where you can execute SQL code in R, my question is basically, is there some library like sqldf in python

Comment: Sorry, our imaginations are poor. Please provide some concrete data and what you _actually_ want.

Comment: `print df`? lol

Comment: What you want is not possible. Dataframes are no SQL databases and can not be queried like one.

Comment: the closest thing to what you want is this : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html and it's not SQL.

Comment: I can only provide the package I am using `pandasql`

Comment: **If you actually have a SQL database you want to query** into a pandas dataframe, you can use [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) with an ADBC Connection, SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This is not what [`pandas.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is supposed to do. You can look at package `pandasql` (same like `sqldf` in R  )

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'Customer A', '123 Street', np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', np.nan, '333 Street'],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '444 Street', '333 Street'],
              [1233, 'Customer B', '444 Street', '666 Street']], columns=
['ID', 'Customer', 'Billing Address', 'Shipping Address'])

q1 = """SELECT ID FROM df """

print(ps.sqldf(q1, locals()))

     ID
0  1234
1  1234
2  1233
3  1233
```

---

**Update 2020-07-10**

> update the `pandasql`

```
ps.sqldf("select * from df")
```

Comment: I get this error due to numpy not being imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: @Jas that was just data import if you change the np.nan to 1000 , it will gone

Comment: FYI, it doesn't look like this works anymore. I get the error `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'`. It might work on older versions of `pandas`; I'm using v1.3.4.

Comment: @MattSosna it still work for me ~

Comment: Not sure if pandasql is maintained anymore. DuckDb might be a better option
Performance benchmark --> https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html

Comment: @Pramit pandasql's last commit was 8 years ago. I think it's safe to say it's not being maintained

Answer (score 36):

Much better solution is to use duckdb. It is much faster than sqldf because it does not have to load the entire data into sqlite and load back to pandas.

```
pip install duckdb
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import duckdb
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"i":[1, 2, 3, 4], "j":["one", "two", "three", "four"]})

duckdb.query("SELECT * FROM test_df where i>2").df() # returns a result dataframe
```

Performance improvement over pandasql:
test data NYC yellow cabs ~120mb of csv data

```py
nyc = pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2021-01.csv',low_memory=False)
```

```py
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
```

```py
pysqldf("SELECT * FROM nyc where trip_distance>10")
# wall time 16.1s
```

```py
duckdb.query("SELECT * FROM nyc where trip_distance>10").df()
# wall time 183ms
```

A improvement of speed of roughly 100x

This article gives good details and claims 1000x improvement over pandasql:
https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html

Answer (score 29):

After some time of using this I realised the easiest way is to just do

```
from pandasql import sqldf

output = sqldf("select * from df")
```

Works like a charm where `df` is a pandas dataframe
You can install pandasql: https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/

Comment: Nice , I still with the old version pandasql , also update the my answer, thanks ~

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a new package that I just released, called dataframe_sql. This gives you the ability to query pandas dataframes using SQL just as you want to. You can find the package [here](https://github.com/zbrookle/dataframe_sql)

Comment: i was not able to find a conda distribution for the same and our support team can only use conda tools to install packages, not pip. Do you have any plan on releasing it?

Comment: @Sajal I can certainly look into it, would you mind raising this as an issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `DataFrame.query(condition)` to return a subset of the data frame matching `condition` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

df.query('C < 6')
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5


df.query('2*B <= C')
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2


df.query('A % 2 == 0')
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
2  6  7  8
```

This is basically the same effect as an SQL statement, except the `SELECT * FROM df WHERE` is implied.

Comment: You can add. `df.eval` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html

Comment: In the 3 examples given above, it's easy to understand the 3 different conditions. If one uses normal subsetting, the same can be achieved though with very similar code: df[df['C'] < 6], df[2*df['B'] <= df['C']] and df[df['A'] % 2 == 0]. I don't see why one would like to SQL anyway. Pandas even has methods like 'groupby" that can be applied to a dataframe to achieve the same as what e.g. a groupby query would return

Comment: @Dobedani -- yup, agree that's the preferred syntax.  The reason I go with `df.query()` is in cases where I don't want to rewrite the dataframe name.  This is common during exploratory data analysis when I might have lots of dataframes I want to run the same stuff on and sticking to method chaining like `.query()` let's me simply swap the variable at the beginning of the chain.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution than `pandassql` would be [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python). The way it handles the table name mapping to a dataframe object is a little cleaner imo. I have not evaluated performance though.

Comment: From Leo Liu's answer: This article gives good details and claims 1000x improvement over pandasql: https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use the tools that do what they do best:

1. Install postgresql
2. Connect to the database:

> from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
> import urllib.parse 
> engconnect = "{0}://{1}:{2}@{3}:{4}/{5}".format(dialect,user_uenc, pw_uenc, host,port, dbname)
> dbengine = create_engine(engconnect)
> database = dbengine.connect()

3. Dump the dataframe into postgres

> df.to_sql('mytablename', database, if_exists='replace')

4. Write your query with all the SQL nesting your brain can handle.

> myquery = "select distinct * from mytablename"

5. Create a dataframe by running the query:

> newdf = pd.read_sql(myquery, database)

Comment: oh the horror, please don't do this in real life

Comment: That's basically what pandasql does with sqlalchemy, except it's a sqlite db by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [FugueSQL](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue)

```sh
pip install fugue[sql]
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from fugue_sql import fsql

comics_df = pd.DataFrame({'book': ['Secret Wars 8',
                                   'Tomb of Dracula 10',
                                   'Amazing Spider-Man 252',
                                   'New Mutants 98',
                                   'Eternals 1',
                                   'Amazing Spider-Man 300',
                                   'Department of Truth 1'],
                          'publisher': ['Marvel', 'Marvel', 'Marvel', 'Marvel', 'Marvel', 'Marvel', 'Image'],
                          'grade': [9.6, 5.0, 7.5, 8.0, 9.2, 6.5, 9.8],
                          'value': [400, 2500, 300, 600, 400, 750, 175]})

# which of my books are graded above 8.0?
query = """
SELECT book, publisher, grade, value FROM comics_df
WHERE grade > 8.0
PRINT
"""

fsql(query).run()
```

Output

```sh
PandasDataFrame
book:str                                                      |publisher:str|grade:double|value:long
--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+----------
Secret Wars 8                                                 |Marvel       |9.6         |400       
Eternals 1                                                    |Marvel       |9.2         |400       
Department of Truth 1                                         |Image        |9.8         |175       
Total count: 3
```

#### References

<sup>https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/beginner/beginner_sql.html</sup>

<sup>https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/10/query-pandas-dataframes-sql.html</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [RBQL](https://pypi.org/project/rbql/) which provides SQL-like query language that allows using Python expression inside SELECT and WHERE statements. It also provides a convenient `%rbql` magic command to use in Jupyter/IPyhon:

```py
# Get some test data:
!pip install vega_datasets
from vega_datasets import data
my_cars_df = data.cars()
# Install and use RBQL:
!pip install rbql
%load_ext rbql
%rbql SELECT * FROM my_cars_df WHERE a.Horsepower > 100 ORDER BY a.Weight_in_lbs DESC
```

In this example `my_cars_df` is a Pandas Dataframe.

You can try it in this demo Google Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_cFPtnQUxILP0RE2_DBlqIfXaEzT-oZ6?usp=sharing).