# Pandas convert list of dictionaries (GA output) into dataframe(s) that makes sense

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, google-analytics-api, lucidchart

I have been struggling with this logic. I am getting data from google analytics in this format, per user per site. (So these are all the activities that one user performed on the site) I cannot change the format in which I receive the data.

PROBLEM: I am running a loop through all of the users and get this output for each user. I want to put this data into a data frame in order to use it later. The problem I have, is the 'activities':[{.....},{......}] part, I cannot figure out to store all of this data in a way that makes sense.

```
{'sampleRate': 1,
 'sessions': [{'activities': [{'activityTime': '2020-01-08T16:00:44.399101Z',
                               'activityType': 'PAGEVIEW',
                               'campaign': '(not set)',
                               'channelGrouping': 'Direct',
                               'customDimension': [{'index': 1}],
                               'hostname': 'company.domain.com',
                               'keyword': '(not set)',
                               'landingPagePath': '/login',
                               'medium': '(none)',
                               'pageview': {'pagePath': '/thepath',
                                            'pageTitle': 'thecurrentwebpage'},
                               'source': '(direct)'},
                              {'activityTime': '2020-01-08T15:58:43.077293Z',
                               'activityType': 'PAGEVIEW',
                               'campaign': '(not set)',
                               'channelGrouping': 'Direct',
                               'customDimension': [{'index': 1}],
                               'hostname': 'company.domain.com',
                               'keyword': '(not set)',
                               'landingPagePath': '/login',
                               'medium': '(none)',
                               'pageview': {'pagePath': '/theotherpath',
                                            'pageTitle': 'thecurrentwebpage'},
                               'source': '(direct)'}],
               'dataSource': 'web',
               'deviceCategory': 'desktop',
               'platform': 'Windows',
               'sessionDate': '2020-01-08',
               'sessionId': '1578491x03d'},
              {'activities': [{'activityTime': '2019-12-28T21:58:48.993944Z',
                               'activityType': 'PAGEVIEW',
                               'campaign': '(not set)',.....
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

For each user's data to be stored in tables organised as such: [image: Lucid chart brainstorming of ERD layouts]

If there is some logic error in the picture, I am happy to change what I have. I just need the data to work.

PS:
I need to use SQL and ERD's in LucidChart, I have never before had to manipulate data in this format. Any help, to get the data -that is structured like the example above- into a dataframe(s).

EDITED:

Example of two different types of activities (the activity is always classified as either 'pageview' or 'event'):

```
{'activityTime':
                               # Pageview activity
                               '2020-01-08T15:48:38.012671Z',
                               'activityType': 'PAGEVIEW',
                               'campaign': '(not set)',
                               'channelGrouping': 'Direct',
                               'customDimension': [{'index': 1}],
                               'hostname': 'company.domain.com',
                               'keyword': '(not set)',
                               'landingPagePath': '/login',
                               'medium': '(none)',
                               'pageview': {'pagePath': '/login',
                                            'pageTitle': 'titleofthepage'},
                               'source': '(direct)'},

                              # Event activity
                              {'activityTime': '2020-01-08T15:48:37.915105Z',
                               'activityType': 'EVENT',
                               'campaign': '(not set)',
                               'channelGrouping': 'Direct',
                               'customDimension': [{'index': 1}],
                               'event': {'eventAction': 'Successfully Logged '
                                                        'In',
                                         'eventCategory': 'Auth',
                                         'eventCount': '1',
                                         'eventLabel': '(not set)'},
                               'hostname': 'company.domain.com',
                               'keyword': '(not set)',
                               'landingPagePath': '/login',
                               'medium': '(none)',
                               'source': '(direct)'}]
```

Comment: Why do you split Table Activity, Event and Pageview? They can be all in the same table or is there a reason for this? In addition how do you get eventCategory, eventCount, eventLabel and eventAction?

Comment: Thank you, so the output can either be pageview or event (to my knowledge, pageview: when the user switched to a different page while event: something that was done on the same page). There are lots of activities in one [{'activity': ...}] I will send you an example of 'pageview'-activity and an example of a 'event'-activity... In other words, there are lots of activities and a activity can either have event ouputs or pageview outputs, it will never be both.

Comment: If all three of the tables can be in one table, we can certainly do it that way, whichever way works best

Comment: It makes sense now. There are as far as I know advantage to store it in your table and disadvantages. Advantages: No joins, Disadvantages: Redudance (in your case not really), NULL values, bigger table (depending on your size doesn't fit all into memory).  (I'm not an expert in databases but that is what I know) but with the information you shared you can do both, up to you

Comment: Nice, thank you. How do I actually go about putting this data into a dataframe

Comment: I can show it to you maybe later. Have some private issues and no time right now. (if there is no answer later when I have time). But basically you parse the json, iterate through and create a dictionary. With a dictionary you can easy create a panda dataframe.

Comment: Is there a way SQL can make this simpler? I am obligated to use SQL

Comment: you can also use SQL in Pandas (I don't use it a lot) but that is independent to creating the table/dataframe. Either way you have to create table for a SQL database or dataframe for pandas. And for that you need data processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
str = """{"sampleRate": 1,
 "sessions": [{"activities": [{"activityTime": "2020-01-08T16:00:44.399101Z",
                               "activityType": "PAGEVIEW",
                               "campaign": "(not set)",
                               "channelGrouping": "Direct",
                               "customDimension": [{"index": 1}],
                               "hostname": "company.domain.com",
                               "keyword": "(not set)",
                               "landingPagePath": "/login",
                               "medium": "(none)",
                               "pageview": {"pagePath": "/thepath",
                                            "pageTitle": "thecurrentwebpage"},
                               "source": "(direct)"},
                              {"activityTime": "2020-01-08T15:48:37.915105Z",
                               "activityType": "EVENT",
                               "campaign": "(not set)",
                               "channelGrouping": "Direct",
                               "customDimension": [{"index": 1}],
                               "event": {"eventAction": "Successfully Logged In",
                                         "eventCategory": "Auth",
                                         "eventCount": "1",
                                         "eventLabel": "(not set)"},
                               "hostname": "company.domain.com",
                               "keyword": "(not set)",
                               "landingPagePath": "/login",
                               "medium": "(none)",
                               "source": "(direct)"}],
               "dataSource": "web",
               "deviceCategory": "desktop",
               "platform": "Windows",
               "sessionDate": "2020-01-08",
               "sessionId": "1578491x03d"}]}"""


data = json.loads(str)

session_keys = "sessionId,dataSource,deviceCategory,platform,sessionDate,DB_id".split(",")
event_keys = "activityTime,eventCategory,eventCount,eventLabel,eventAction".split(",")
pageview_keys = "activityTime,pageTitle,pagePath".split(",")

sessions = {k:[] for k in session_keys}
events = {k:[] for k in event_keys}
pageviews = {k:[] for k in pageview_keys}
activities = {"sessionId":[],"activityTime":[]}

for session in data["sessions"]:
    for easy_key in session_keys[:5]:
        sessions[easy_key] += [session[easy_key]]
    for activity in session["activities"]:
        activity_time = activity["activityTime"]
        activities["sessionId"] += [session["sessionId"]]
        activities["activityTime"] += [activity_time]
        if activity["activityType"] == "PAGEVIEW":
            pageviews["activityTime"] += [activity_time]
            pageviews["pageTitle"] += [activity["pageview"]["pageTitle"]]
            pageviews["pagePath"] += [activity["pageview"]["pagePath"]]
        elif activity["activityType"] == "EVENT":
            events["activityTime"] += [activity_time]
            events["eventAction"] += [activity["event"]["eventAction"]]
            events["eventCategory"] += [activity["event"]["eventCategory"]]
            events["eventCount"] += [activity["event"]["eventCount"]]
            events["eventLabel"] += [activity["event"]["eventLabel"]]
        else:
            print("Unknown Activity: {}".format(activity["activityType"]))

    sessions["DB_id"] += [0]

df_session = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sessions)
df_session.set_index('sessionId', inplace=True)
df_event = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(events)
df_event.set_index('activityTime', inplace=True)
df_pageview = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pageviews)
df_pageview.set_index('activityTime', inplace=True)
df_activities = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(activities)
```

## Output each DF:

```
#df_session:

            dataSource deviceCategory platform sessionDate  DB_id
sessionId                                                        
1578491x03d        web        desktop  Windows  2020-01-08      0



#df_activities:
     sessionId                 activityTime
0  1578491x03d  2020-01-08T16:00:44.399101Z
1  1578491x03d  2020-01-08T15:48:37.915105Z



#df_event:
                            eventCategory eventCount eventLabel             eventAction
activityTime                                                                           
2020-01-08T15:48:37.915105Z          Auth          1  (not set)  Successfully Logged In



#df_pageview:
                                     pageTitle  pagePath
activityTime                                            
2020-01-08T16:00:44.399101Z  thecurrentwebpage  /thepath
```

## Output example join

```
#As example for a join, I only want the event data
df_sa = df_activities.join(df_session, on="sessionId").join(df_event,on="activityTime",how="right") 

print(df_sa)
```

```
     sessionId                 activityTime dataSource deviceCategory platform sessionDate  DB_id eventCategory eventCount eventLabel             eventAction
1  1578491x03d  2020-01-08T15:48:37.915105Z        web        desktop  Windows  2020-01-08      0          Auth          1  (not set)  Successfully Logged In
```

## Schema

It is the same as you specified above with 2 changes:

1. The Table session doesn't have a column activities anymore.
2. The Table Activity has an additional column sessionId.

## SQL

How to execute SQL in pandas Dataframe you can look up online probably to much to cover here. See here for example: [Executing an SQL query over a pandas dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865608/executing-an-sql-query-over-a-pandas-dataset)

## How to get the data

Some examples: (but in the end you have to figure it out yourself if you want something specific, I don't make an SQL course here)

- If you only want session data: Query `df_session`
- If you want all
  activities: Query `df_event` and `df_pageview`
- If you want all
  activities and combined with sessions: join `df_session` with
  `df_activities` then join with `df_event` and `df_pageview`

## I don't want a Dataframe... I need MYSQL Database (or something else)

Nothing easier than that. The dataframe are in a "properly" database format.

Example for Session:

```
for index, row in df_sessions.iterrows():
    # for event and pageview the index would be activityTime
    # the df activities don't have a specific index
    sessionId = index 
    dataSource = row['dataSource']
    deviceCategory = row['deviceCategory']
    platform = row['platform']
    sessionDate = row['sessionDate']
    DB_id = row['DB_id']
    # function to save a row in a SQL DB basically:
    # INSERT INTO session (sessionId,dataSource,deviceCategory,platform,sessionDate,DB_id) VALUES(x,x,x,x,x,x)
    save_to_sql(sessionId,dataSource,deviceCategory,platform,sessionDate,DB_id)
```

the `save_to_sql` is your own implementation depending on what database you are using. And it would not fit this question to explain that to you.

## Comments

1. `DB_id` don't know the origin of this value. I set it to 0.

Comment: this is honestly the most thorough answer I have ever received on this platform. Thank you so much for all the help! Have a great one