# Converting SQL query into pandas syntax

Tags: sql, pandas, ms-access

I am very new to Pandas. How do I convert the following query into pandas syntax. I am no longer querying a MS Access table, I am now querying a pandas DataFrame called df.

The query is:

```
SELECT 
    Short_ID, 
    SUM(IIF(Status = 'Completed', 1, 0))) / COUNT (Status) AS completion_metric
FROM 
    PROMIS_LT_Long_ID
GROUP BY 
    Short_ID;
```

The query results would be something like this:

```
Short_ID | completion_metric
---------+------------------
1004     | 0.125
1005     | 0
1004     | 0.5
```

I have created the pandas df with the following code and now I would like to query the pandas DataFrame and obtain the same result as the query above.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 

def connect_to_db():
    db_name = "imuscigrp"
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:SQLDCB301P.uhn.ca\SQLDCB301P;DATABASE=imucsigrp'
                             r';UID=imucsigrp_data_team;PWD=Kidney123!')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor, conn

def completion_metric(): 
    SQL_Query = pd.read-sql_query('SELECT PROMIS_LT_Long_ID.Short_ID, PROMIS_LT_Long_ID.Status FROM PROMIS_LT_Long_ID', conn)
    #converts SQL_Query into Pandas dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns = ["Short_ID", "Status"])
    #querying the df to obtain longitudinal completion metric values 
    
    return
```

Any contributions will help, thank you

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45865608/2144390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some numpy functions for performing similar operations.

For example, [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace the value based on a condition.

```py
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns = ["Short_ID", "Status"])
df["completion_metric"] = np.where(df.Status == "Completed", 1,  0)
```

Then [`numpy.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) to compute an average value for the grouped data.

```py
completion_metric = df.groupby("Short_ID").agg({"completion_metric": np.average})
```

Comment: What is the purpose of writing df["Completion"], you do not use it when you use Numpy average so how will python know that we want to count where Status == "Completed" ?     PS: I am happy to see the Naija name, I'm from Zimbabwe. Good to see another African.

Comment: Should the second bock of code rather be ... .agg({"completion":np.average}) instead of ... .agg({"completion_metric":np.average}) ? If so, then this resolves the previous comment. I have another question though.... so this completion_metric is in the form of a pandas column right? Would it be possible to have the completion_metric column with the corresponding Short_ID because I ned to know which completion metric goes with which Short_ID.

Comment: That was my bad. I have updated the answer.  `df['completion_metric']` should be the averaged field after grouping by `Short_ID`. `completion_metric` is a `pandas.DataFrame`. You have the `Short_ID` and their average `completion_metric` value in the `completion_metric`  dataframe.